# pyenv: python: command not found

Tags: python

I was trying to reinstall my python but now it stopped working. If I try to run `python` (or `python3`), I get the following error message:

```
pyenv: python: command not found

The `python' command exists in these Python versions:
  3.7-dev
```

I was trying to follow suggested solutions I've found, like eg. setting `pyenv global 3.7-dev` and running pyenv `init` but the issue persists. What could be the issue here?

Comment: Mac or Linux? This is probably a PATH issue

Comment: @MattM sorry, forgot to mention. I'm using Linux. But shouldn't it be somehow solved by pyenv itself?

Comment: Not  everything is done by pyenv.  Is this in your `~/.bashrc`? 
`export PATH="/root/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"` and
`eval "$(pyenv init -)"` and
`eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"`

Comment: @MattM I've added it but now I get `pyenv: no such command `virtualenv-init'` error on starting a new terminal / on running this command manually (I've put the commands in the same order as in your comment).

Comment: (Also running just the first two commands does not help. python is still not found, even though the corresponding bin directory is on the path and `pyenv local` command in the project folder shows 3.7-dev version being selected. However, `pyenv global` doesn't change the version.)

Comment: try this for the virtualenv `git clone https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv-virtualenv.git ~/.pyenv/plugins/pyenv-virtualenv`. Make sure all 3 of those previously mentioned lines are in your `.bashrc`, then `source` it or restart your terminal and make sure there's no errors. If its still not showing on your global then it might be worth reinstalling